# Call a java method using cassandra triggers

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I know that java method can be called using database triggers in oracledb. I am new to cassandra and I want to get a similar functionality in cassandra. Would it be possible to call a specific methods using cassandra triggers or is there any way to achieve it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should be done only when you have a real reason to do & you understand what effect triggers will have on the Cassandra's performance...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible, check [CREATE TRIGGER](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html) for details.

Basically, when you will define the trigger you specify the class to load. This has to implement the ITrigger interface. You JAR files needs to be placed in the triggers folder on each node.